# SQL startswith (using `LIKE`) on an expression

Tags: sql

What's an appropriate way to do `startswith(expression)` in SQL?

I can do it with `LIKE ((expression) || '%')`, but it doesn't look very nice to me.

Full query is in form:

```
SELECT …, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM post AS child 
           WHERE child.path LIKE (post.path || '%') 
          AND child.depth >= post.depth)
FROM post WHERE …
```

I suppose it is preferable to use `LIKE` because of DB indexing for this case.

Comment: You are writing a correlated subquery and you are worried about how the like clause looks? Why on earth would you care if the statment looks nice. There are three things to worry about in SQl statments: do it return the correct results, does it perform well (hint correlated subqueries often don't and should be avoided) and is it secure? Looks nice isn't even a close fourth.

Comment: It performs as well as it possibly can (actually, this particular subquery is only done for a subset of all returned objects using CASE WHEN).  Other considerations are not much of a problem either, although in other similar cases concern for security could result in the same question (`post.path` is unescaped, no?  How would I escape it properly in such case? for now it is known to be safe though.)

Comment: Just a question. Is it possible in your data to have `child.path LIKE (post.path || '%') AND child.depth < post.depth` ? If not, the second check is redundant.

Comment: It is indeed logically redundant; but I'm not sure it's unnecessary — it is used in the original sample set of queries and, I suspect, it might increase performance (since filtering by depth first might be more efficient).  But indeed, I am not so sure about that.

Comment: If "Looks nice" means "easy to understand and therefor maintain" I'd argue that that IS important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In standard SQL, you can also say:

```
where position(post.path in child.path) = 1
```

I don't know if your RDBMS supports that. PostgreSQL does.

Comment: Hm-mm, interesting. But wouldn't that perform worse, likely because of not using DB indexing (for LIKE statements that only end with '%')?

Comment: Quite possibly. It depends entirely on whether the query planner is smart enough to notice the ' = 0' and realise that this is a prefix query which can be handled with an index (if there is an index). It's certainly very unlikely to be faster than the LIKE version.

Comment: I think it must be 1 instead of 0. E.g. select position('ab' in 'abcd') returns 1. The return value 0 means that the search string does not occur in the other string.

Comment: @StefanB You're right. I have corrected my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 38):

Just use `LIKE 'input%'`.  I.E:

```
WHERE child.path LIKE post.path + '%'
```

(I assume this is for SQL Server, though this syntax probably works elsewhere)

Comment: The syntax will not work on other databases because the + for string concatenation is specific to Microsoft. All standard compliant DBMS use `||`. But apart from that,, I agree the statement should work on other DBMS

Comment: That's what I used (and I did write the same thing in the question).

Answer (score 2):

WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%'
--Finds any values that start with "a"

WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%a'
--Finds any values that end with "a"

WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%'
--Finds any values that have "or" in any position

WHERE CustomerName LIKE '_r%'
--Finds any values that have "r" in the second position

WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a__%'
--Finds any values that start with "a" and are at least 3 characters in length

WHERE ContactName LIKE 'a%o'
--Finds any values that start with "a" and ends with "o"

-- Case insensitive
2
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE upper(my_column) LIKE 'SEARCHED %';
-- starts with

3
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE upper(my_column) LIKE '% SEARCHED';
-- ends with

4
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE upper(my_column) LIKE '%SEARCHED%';  -- contains

Comment: Note that in all your examples the pattern is constant. The question is about non-constant pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`where  DATE LIKE '[(SELECT STR(YEAR(GETDATE())-1))]%'`

`WHERE child.path LIKE '[(SELECT STR(YEAR(GETDATE())-1))]%' (post.path || '%')`